Overlay NSTextLayoutFragment with CATextLayer
I'd like to overlay a NSTextLayoutFragment with a CATextLayer. The idea being that I could then hide the fragment, animate the CATextLayerand then unhide the NSTextLayoutFragment at the end of animation. But, I'm having trouble getting a perfect alignment between the two, They seem to be off by a pixel or so on the y-axis.

In this screenshot, the pink text is from TextKit, while the blue one is my overlaid CATextLayer. The mismatch seems to be more pronounced with certain fonts. The screenshot is using Roboto font. The code on my github and below uses systemFont (as I figured that would be more readily available).
I have a sample project here on GitHub
The relevant code extracted from the project
TextKit Setup
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    var textView: TextView {
        self.view as! TextView
    }

    var textLayoutManager: NSTextLayoutManager!
    var textContentStorage: NSTextContentStorage!
    var textContainer: NSTextContainer!
    internal var fragmentLayerMap: NSMapTable<NSTextLayoutFragment, CALayer>!

    override func viewDidAppear() {
        let textContainer = NSTextContainer(size: view.bounds.size)
        self.textContainer = textContainer

        let textLayoutManager = NSTextLayoutManager()
        textLayoutManager.textContainer = textContainer
        self.textLayoutManager = textLayoutManager

        let textContentStorage = NSTextContentStorage()
        self.textContentStorage = textContentStorage

        textContentStorage.addTextLayoutManager(textLayoutManager)

        textLayoutManager.textViewportLayoutController.delegate = self
        textView.layer?.delegate = self

        let text = "#"
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [.font: NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40)])
        attributedString.addAttributes([.foregroundColor: NSColor.systemPink], range: NSMakeRange(0, 1))
        textContentStorage.textStorage?.setAttributedString(attributedString)

        textView.layer?.setNeedsLayout()
    }

    private func createOrGetUpdatedLayer(for textLayoutFragment: NSTextLayoutFragment) -> TextLayoutFragmentLayer {
        if let layer = fragmentLayerMap.object(forKey: textLayoutFragment) as? TextLayoutFragmentLayer {
            let oldPosition = layer.position
            let oldBounds = layer.bounds
            layer.updateGeometry()
            if oldBounds != layer.bounds {
                layer.setNeedsDisplay()
            }

            if oldPosition != layer.position {
                animatePosition(layer, from: oldPosition, to: layer.position)
            }

            return layer
        } else {
            let layer = TextLayoutFragmentLayer(layoutFragment: textLayoutFragment, padding: xOriginPadding)
            fragmentLayerMap.setObject(layer, forKey: textLayoutFragment)
            return layer
        }
    }

    func add(textLayoutFragment: NSTextLayoutFragment) {
        let fragmentLayer = createOrGetUpdatedLayer(for: textLayoutFragment)

        textView.add(fragmentLayer: fragmentLayer)
    }
}

TextFragmentLayer
class TextLayoutFragmentLayer: NoDefaultAnimationCALayer {
    private(set) var layoutFragment: NSTextLayoutFragment!

    init(layoutFragment: NSTextLayoutFragment, padding: CGFloat) {
        super.init()
        commonInit()
        self.layoutFragment = layoutFragment
        updateGeometry()
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        self.backgroundColor = NSColor.white.cgColor
    }

    func updateGeometry() {
        bounds = NSRect(origin: .zero, size: layoutFragment.renderingSurfaceBounds.size)
        position = CGPoint(x: bounds.size.width/2, y: bounds.size.height/2)
    }

    override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
        layoutFragment?.draw(at: .zero, in: ctx)
    }
}

NSTextViewportLayoutControllerDelegate
extension ViewController: NSTextViewportLayoutControllerDelegate {
    public func viewportBounds(for textViewportLayoutController: NSTextViewportLayoutController) -> CGRect {
// This is from Apple sample Code - Using TextKit2
        let overdrawRect = textView.preparedContentRect
        let visibleRect = textView.visibleRect
        var minY: CGFloat = 0
        var maxY: CGFloat = 0
        if overdrawRect.intersects(visibleRect) {
            // Use preparedContentRect for vertical overdraw and ensure visibleRect is included at the minimum,
            // the width is always bounds width for proper line wrapping.
            minY = min(overdrawRect.minY, max(visibleRect.minY, 0))
            maxY = max(overdrawRect.maxY, visibleRect.maxY)
        } else {
            // We use visible rect directly if preparedContentRect does not intersect.
            // This can happen if overdraw has not caught up with scrolling yet, such as before the first layout.
            minY = visibleRect.minY
            maxY = visibleRect.maxY
        }

        let bounds = view.bounds
        let viewportBounds = CGRect(x: bounds.minX, y: minY, width: bounds.width, height: maxY - minY)

        return viewportBounds
    }

    public func textViewportLayoutController(_ textViewportLayoutController: NSTextViewportLayoutController, configureRenderingSurfaceFor textLayoutFragment: NSTextLayoutFragment) {
        add(textLayoutFragment: textLayoutFragment)
    }
}

Code that adds Overlaid CATextLayer
@IBAction func overlayTextLayer(_ sender: Any) {
        let font = NSFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40)
        let fontSize: CGFloat = 40
        let overlay = CATextLayer()
        overlay.font = font
        overlay.fontSize = fontSize
        overlay.foregroundColor = NSColor.systemBlue.cgColor
        overlay.string = "#"
        let overlayCharactersSize = overlay.preferredFrameSize()
        overlay.bounds = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: controlCharactersSize)
        overlay.position = CGPoint(x: overlayCharacterSize.width/2, y: overlayCharacterSize.height/2)

        textView.add(fragmentLayer: overlay)
    }

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks
